# How to assign local variables to instance variables of the same name in TCL?

Tags: tcl

In Java I can use constructor parameters with the same name as instance variables:

```
class Obj {
    String instanceVar;

    Obj(String instanceVar) {
        this.instanceVar = instanceVar;
    }
}
```

Can this be done in TCL ?

(The closest I can get in TCL is):

```
oo::class create Obj {
    variable instanceVar

    constructor {_instanceVar} {
        set instanceVar _instanceVar
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I find this irritating too! What I do (when I don't just pick different names for instance variables) is this:

```sh
constructor {instanceVar} {
    set [my varname instanceVar] $instanceVar
}
```

or (for example):

```sh
constructor {instanceVar} {
    namespace upvar [namespace current] instanceVar iv
    set iv $instanceVar
}
```

but yes, I'm not very happy with that. Constructors probably ought to do something smarter in the case where the mapped variable name is the same… but that's tricky in itself for a whole complex range of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

When I need this, I include a small method I call `init` (can be done using a mixin or superclass containing other useful methods):

```
method init {args} {
    variable {*}$args
}
```

This allows me to do this:

```
constructor {instanceVar} {
    my init instanceVar $instanceVar
}
```

If there are more variables, you can just add them to the `my init` call.